# How to allow a CharacterController to pass through walls?

Tags: unity, c#, movement, collision-resolution, character-controller

I'm developing a game in which bot-controlled billboards pursue you.

If the bot gets stuck behind a wall for a while, not able to catch the player, I want the bot to pass through the wall.

I'm using a `CharacterController` and I don't know how to disable collision and allow it to pass through other colliders.

Comment: Are you sure you are still using the long obsolete unityscript language and not C# as your scripting language?

Comment: Following Philipp's comment, I've changed your tag to `C#` - you're probably not using `UnityScript` unless you're using a version of Unity from circa 2015 or earlier. Would you be interested in solutions that allow the bots to go *around* the walls, like using a `NavMesh` and `NavmeshAgent` for pathfinding? That might save you from collision hacks that could be perceived by the player as "the AI is cheating" or "this game is buggy".

Comment: My bad, yes I’m using C#. I thought UnityScript and C# are the same… I’m clearly new here. I have already used NavMesh for pathfinding. But sometime, the player go to places where the Agent cannot access I always want the bot to follow the player no matter what, but I don’t want it to teleport straight to the player either. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unity has a "[Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)" that lets you define interactions between different layers. I'm guessing that you will want to:

1. Assign the player to a Player layer.
2. Assign the billboards to an Enemy or Billboard layer.
3. Assuming 3D, update the level you have so that walls are a separate layer from the floor.
4. Update the Layer Collision Matrix so that the Player collides with the floors and the walls.
5. Update the Layer Collision Matrix so that the Billboards collide with ONLY the floors.

Per DMGergory's comment, if you want to temporarily do this based on how long the enemy is stuck, here are some ideas:

- Teleport the enemy closer if it gets too far away from the player. Should be pretty effective and a lot of games do this, not always to the player's enjoyment though.
- Setup another layer in the collision matrix which does what I describe above (doesn't collide with walls), and switch the enemy to that layer, at least temporarily, if it gets to far or hasn't moved much recently (and it's supposed to be).
- Disable collision (Colliders) on walls that are far enough away from the player (off screen?).

Comment: It sounds like OP wants the enemies to usually be blocked by walls, but selectively disable collision after an enemy has been stuck for a threshold duration. Any tips on how to do that?